# How can I capture audio-video from webcam using HTML5 which supports both the browsers firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am creating th web application for sharing live video message using php.
I have search for the script and I got https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/PHP/ this script.

But the problem is that it's run on firefox(video+audio) but not support for chrome.

So is there any solution for this? so that the script that can support on both firefox and chrome.

And one thing I dont want to use the flash; as I want to make my application support over mobile as well.

Comment: I think, the RecordRTC project is using the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API which is supported only by firefox at the moment.

Comment: RecordRTC is supporting both Chrome and Firefox. It uses WebM and WebAudio hacks to support audio/video recording in Chrome. The referenced demo MUST be working in Chrome. You should read this wiki: [How to configure PHP for RecordRTC?](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/wiki/PHP-Upload-Issues)